# Negative MNIST - Trying to understand what's going on here

Tags: machine-learning, python, pytorch, gradient-descent, mnist

I'm new to machine learning and pytorch and any insight would be greatly appreciated. I've been playing around with the MNIST number recognition dataset and thought it would be interesting to train different models on the negative images.

One model in particular yielded interesting results. The model is just three fully connected layers with the ReLU activation. When trained on the non-negative images, this is what the learning process looked like.

[image: non-negative]

On the other hand, when trained on negative images, this is what the learning process looks like.

[image]
[image]
[image]

At first I wondered if this was an exploding gradient issue due to high activation values, but when testing with a model with the sigmoid activation function resulted more consistent results and smoother changes in loss, and from my understanding models with sigmoid activations are more susceptible to gradient explosion.

Is it just some bug in my code? Here's the code snippet just in case.

```
class Network2(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Network2, self).__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784, 200)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(200, 100)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(100, 10)
    
  def forward(self, x):
    x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    x = nn.functional.relu(x)
    x = self.fc2(x)
    x = nn.functional.relu(x)
    x = self.fc3(x)
    x = nn.functional.relu(x)
    return x
```

```
# traning code
eta = 0.1
epochs = 20

net2 = network.Network2()
print(net2)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net2.parameters(), lr=eta)
net2.zero_grad()

val_accs = []
val_loss = []
train_accs = []
train_loss = []
grads = []
    
total_loss = 0.
total_acc = (0, 0)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print(f"epoch {epoch}")
    
    for i, (X, y) in enumerate(train_loader):
        net2.train() # training mode
        
        output = net2(X)
        loss = criterion(output, y)
        total_loss += loss.item()
        total_acc = tuple(a + b for a, b in zip(total_acc, accuracy(output, y)))
        
        loss.backward()
        
        if i + 1 == len(train_loader):
            grads.append(net2.fc1.weight.grad.detach().numpy().flatten())
        
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if i % 100 == 99: # for every 100th batch
            net2.eval() # evaluation mode
            
            with torch.no_grad():
                total_val_loss = 0.
                val_acc = (0, 0)
                for j, (val_X, val_y) in enumerate(validation_loader):
                    # evaluation loss and accuracy check
                    output = net2(val_X)
                    val_acc = tuple(a + b for a, b in zip(val_acc, accuracy(output, val_y)))
                    total_val_loss += criterion(output, val_y).item()
                print(f" evaluation accuracy: {100 * val_acc[0] / val_acc[1]}")
                val_accs.append(val_acc)
                val_loss.append(total_val_loss / len(validation_loader))
                
            print(f" training accuracy: {100 * total_acc[0] / total_acc[1]}")
            train_accs.append(total_acc)
            train_loss.append(total_loss / 100)
                       
            total_loss = 0.
            total_acc = (0, 0)
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what would happen if you subtracted 0.5 (or whatever is the middle point) from the input images and then tried both non-negated and negated versions. Maybe it is to do with the thing that the digits are somehow "sparse" in the surrounding white area.

Comment: @Valentas You mean so that only the outline of the digits are highlighted? Ex) abs(x - 0.5) so that fully activated or deactivated pixels have similar activation?

Comment: Yes, but maybe without abs, one version with x-0.5 and another negated version with -x+0.5.

Comment: But thinking more about this, I am not sure anymore. Because weights are initialized symmetrically it should work the same in both cases. Maybe there is some bug in your code.

Comment: @Valentas ah, so sort of normalize the training dataset? Also, how would weight symmetry imply the training on negative images will be similar to training on the original images?

Comment: I've tried out what you suggested. 
For (x-.5) this was the training performance: https://github.com/slothman3878/pytorch-playground/blob/main/images/normalized_network2_00.png
For (.5-x) this was the training performance:  https://github.com/slothman3878/pytorch-playground/blob/main/images/normalized_negative_network2_00.png

It seemed like in both cases, the performance was heavily dependent on the ordering of the training dataset.